# Drupal 8: Pdf (print) search results (search_api)

Tags: 8, search, files

I am using the Entity PDF plugin in Drupal 8, that does a good job in exporting to PDF nodes, but seems to exclude other scenarios such as Search Result list.

Anyone can provide some hints how would a PDF export be implemented for  search results?

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_entity_view_alter() to hidden PDF export link. Sample

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

function examples_entity_view_alter(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  $type = $entity->getType();
  $mode = $display->getMode();
  //Replace node type with text **page**
  if ($type == 'page' && $mode == 'search_result') {
    unset($build['entity_print_view']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I did not want to hide, but create a HTML template that would later be pushed to the PDF generator. THe hooks helps in locating a section to place a link...